# Bash keybindings that match those of gedit?

Tags: bash, gedit, shortcut-keys

I want to have the same keybindings in gedit and in bash. Namely all the selections, also cut, copy and paste.

I know there are some important ones that are already taken (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, etc), still... I want to have the same workflow in my text editor and shell of choice.

Anyone has got around this?

Answer (score 4):

There is some information about key-binding in this [bash reference manual](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/bash/bashref_92.html).
To edit key bindings in gnome-terminal, go to Edit->KeyBoard Shortcuts.

While I'm not convinced that what you want to do is absolutely impossible (this is linux after all), I do believe that it will turn into more trouble than it's worth.  Editors and shells are meant to be used for very different purposes and were designed with these very different purposes in mind.  In the long run, I think you'll be better off learning how to use each tool as it was intended to be used (especially if you ever have to use someone else's computer).  Switching between editor and shell becomes second nature with just a little practice.

Update:
As pointed out by djeikyb in the comments, bash does support vi mappings.  If you are willing to learn how to use vi, that may be what you are looking for.  Here is a quick write up on [vi key bindings in bash, with cheat sheet.](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Otoh, some awesome person patched bash to allow vi style bindings. The first command I run on a new install is `echo "set -o vi" >> ~/.bashrc; . ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @djeikyb I am so very glad you told me this.  I find myself in a new level of vi euphoria.

Comment: I've used vi in and out for weeks, I just can't get my mindset to work with it. I would not be using gedit if that was the case :P

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible: on the one hand you have a terminal (which hosts a bash shell) and where - as you say - some combinations are already taken. On the other hand, you use gedit which doesn't allow changing key combinations.